# Does PhoneGap support file open and file transfer and local storage for these operating systems?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am a beginner and I was reading the documents and became a bit confused. I am writing an app that I want to work on all the following : Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8 devices. I need to download files and open them using native apps and also need local storage. in this link: in platform support table,
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview

I see that local storage and File transfers are marked as partial for windows phone 8 in the table. However when I check the actual document for Filetransfer:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

I see windows phone 8 in the supported platforms. So my question is which one is correct? Can I reach these goals or are they not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Phonegap Document** -

For **File Transfer**

**Supported Platforms** :-

```
Android
BlackBerry WebWorks (OS 5.0 and higher)
iOS
Windows Phone 7 and 8
Windows 8
```

So File transfer will work on windows phone.
It does support local storage also. So rest of android and IOS no problem with these two.
Better you make some sample app and check.

Best luck.

Comment: Thank you so much. Then do you know what they mean by partial in the table in the first link I gave?

Answer (score 0):

It does support local storage. If the partially supported local storage suffices your needs, you can still go ahead.
You should probably test it yourself by creating a test project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see but I am not sure what you mean by partially? I mean what is not exactly supported. Also What about the file downloading and opening using native apps? Thanks again!